# R Merge two rows in one

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I'm beginner in R and stuck on a problem with merging some rows.

```
library(data.table)

ticket_id <- c(1,21,31,33,35,101)
depart_city <- c("Dortmund", "Lviv", "Kyiv", "Kyiv", "Kharkiv", "Lviv")
arrival_city <- c("Lviv", "Odessa","Lviv" , "Lviv", "Lviv", "Kharkiv")
name <- c("Jon", "Jon", "Tom", "Tom", "Ivan", "Ivan")
course <- c("L-NY", "NY-M", "K-D", "K-D", "P-C", "P-C")
depart_date <- c("2022-10-07", "2022-10-08", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-08")
price <- c(19,25,70,14,5,13)
tickets <- data.table(ticket_id, depart_city, arrival_city, name, course, depart_date, price)
```

What I'm expecting to get

```
ticket_id1 <- c(1,31,33,35,101)
ticket_id_domestic1 <- c(21,0,0,0,0)
depart_city1 <- c("Dortmund", "Kyiv", "Kyiv", "Kharkiv", "Lviv")
arrival_city1 <- c("Odessa", "Lviv", "Lviv", "Lviv", "Kharkiv")
name1 <- c("Jon", "Tom", "Tom", "Ivan", "Ivan")
course1 <- c("L-NY", "K-D", "K-D", "P-C", "P-c")
course_domestic1 <- c(0, "NY-M", 0, 0, 0)
depart_date1 <- c("2022-10-07", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-07", "2022-10-08" )
price1 <- c(44,70,14,5,13) 
tickets1 <- data.table(ticket_id1, ticket_id_domestic1, depart_city1, arrival_city1, name1, course1, course_domestic1, depart_date1, price1)
```

As we see from entry table, there are some tickets.
Passanger Jon travelled from Dortmund to Odessa with transfer in Lviv, Tom bought 2 tickets from Kyiv to Lviv and Ivan travelled from Kharkiv to Lviv and then back.

I don't know how to merge only those rows, where person is travelling with transfer (only possible in Lviv) and do not do anything with others. So i would like to get in:

1. ticket_id - put value from Lviv to foreigh city in ticket_id and
   value from domestic city to Lviv in ticket_id_domestic;
2. course - put value from Lviv to foreigh city in course and from Lviv to domestic city in
   course_domestic;
3. depart_date - put value from starting point;
4. price - sum

I would greatly appreciate any hint or solution to my problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way that works at least for your example (I think there is an error in your tickets1 table: NY-M should be in the first row, not the second row?), using the tidyverse package. This assumes there is only one transfer. For this to work, the first trip must come before the second in the table, so we are first arranging by name and departure date. If both trips occur on the same date, you would need some other way to sort your table to make sure the first trip comes before the second. If the ticket_id for the first trip is always smaller than for the second, you can arrange by ticket_id instead. This code first creates some temporary variables to identify which person is a transfer, then constructs your new variables based on transfer, and finally cleans up the temporary variables by selecting only the ones we want to keep. I left off the ones in your variable names for the new table.

```
library(tidyverse)
tickets1 <- tickets %>% arrange(name, depart_date) %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(name_lead = lead(name),
         depart_lead = lead(depart_city),
         arrival_lead = lead(arrival_city),
         ticket_id_domestic = lead(ticket_id),
         course_domestic = lead(course),
         price_lead = lead(price),
         transfer = ifelse(arrival_city == depart_lead & depart_city != arrival_lead, 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(ticket_id_domestic = ifelse(transfer %in% 1, ticket_id_domestic, 0),
         course_domestic = ifelse(transfer %in% 1, course_domestic, 0),
         arrival_city =  ifelse(transfer %in% 1, arrival_lead, arrival_city),
         price = ifelse(transfer %in% 1, price + price_lead, price)) %>%
  filter(!ticket_id %in% ticket_id_domestic) %>%
  dplyr::select(ticket_id, ticket_id_domestic, depart_city, arrival_city, 
                name, course, course_domestic, depart_date, price) %>%
  arrange(ticket_id)
```